# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when installing Udeler (Fedora)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, appimage

I am running Fedora 29. I'm trying to install Udeler [an app to download Udemy videos from courses you are enrolled in]. It is a very small application with an "appImage" extension. I installed and used it fine on Ubuntu LTS 18.4. On Fedora, it gives me this error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it? PS: I googled it, but found nothing relevant.

EDIT: this is the link: https://github.com/FaisalUmair/udemy-downloader-gui
EDIT#2: This is the whole error message:

```
$ ./Udeler-1.6.2-linux-x86_x64.AppImage 
installed: X-AppImage-BuildId=391b0ee0-961e-11a8-2db3-69142b37c780 image: X-AppImage-BuildId=391b0ee0-961e-11a8-2db3-69142b37c780
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only 'simple way' to get it working with Fedora is via the downloader-gui on github:

https://github.com/FaisalUmair/udemy-downloader-gui

Comment: That's what I had downloaded...